# Find block of lines that does not match block format

Tags: vim, sed

I have a big file with following format

```
         0           0           0           0
      5522     -365290     -441287      -78074
    -39490      -30774        7921       82126
   1391898     1139913      792801     2672554
         0           0           0           0
      4906     -366163     -441744      -77614
    -39125      -31009        7332       81061
   1412373     1142806      793817     2837307
         0           0           0           0
```

I need to find those blocks of lines that does not match this format.
For example block of four lines of numbers bounded with zero
lines:

```
         0           0           0           0                                                                                                                    
     15965     -463075     -549574      -89243
    -64152      -45009       17963      103367
   -189486     -165820     -128253     -236536
   1243199     1029337      734157     2290154
         0           0           0           0
```

does not match the format.
I only need to find blocks like these.
I will fix them manually based on the context.

Meanwhile I have following query in vim:

```
/\s0           0\n.*\n.*\n.*\n/^\(\(\s0\)\@!.\)*$
```

Which doesn't really work.
I'm pretty sure that this part:

```
\s0           0\n.*\n.*\n.*\n
```

is ok. But then I'm stuck.
Probably it is better to use `sed` or `awk` to solve it.
Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post samples of expected output in your question and let us know for more clarity, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The standard output of vim search. It just takes you to the next occurrence of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following vim search query does what I was trying to achieve

`/\(\s\+0\)\{4}\n.*\n.*\n.*\n^\(\(\s+0\)\{4}\)\@!`

It finds all line blocks contained between two lines of four `0` and has other number of lines then 3.

`\(\s\+0\)\{4}`  Look for a line of 4 zeros such that, each 0 preceded with at least one whitespace

`\n.*\n.*\n.*` followed by 3 lines of anything

`\n^\(\(\s+0\)\{4}\)\@!` and not followed by line of 4 zeros

So it will find block like this

```
         0           0           0           0                                                                                                                    
     15965     -463075     -549574      -89243
    -64152      -45009       17963      103367
   -189486     -165820     -128253     -236536
   1243199     1029337      734157     2290154
         0           0           0           0
```

And block like this

```
     0           0           0           0                                                                                                                    
 15965     -463075     -549574      -89243
-64152      -45009       17963      103367
     0           0           0           0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume your input file is like below.

```
$ cat block_zeros.txt
         0           0           0           0
      5522     -365290     -441287      -78074
    -39490      -30774        7921       82126
   1391898     1139913      792801     2672554
         0           0           0           0
      4906     -366163     -441744      -77614
    -39125      -31009        7332       81061
   1412373     1142806      793817     2837307
         0           0           0           0
     15965     -463075     -549574      -89243
    -64152      -45009       17963      103367
   -189486     -165820     -128253     -236536
   1243199     1029337      734157     2290154
         0           0           0           0
      5000     -300000     -400000      -70000
    -30000      -30000        7000       80000
         0           0           0           0
$
```

And you need to remove the pattern

```
         0           0           0           0
     15965     -463075     -549574      -89243
    -64152      -45009       17963      103367
   -189486     -165820     -128253     -236536
   1243199     1029337      734157     2290154
         0           0           0           0
```

The expected output is like below.

```
0        0        0        0
5522     -365290  -441287  -78074
-39490   -30774   7921     82126
1391898  1139913  792801   2672554
0        0        0        0
4906     -366163  -441744  -77614
-39125   -31009   7332     81061
1412373  1142806  793817   2837307
0        0        0        0
5000     -300000  -400000  -70000
-30000   -30000   7000     80000
0        0        0        0
```

If the above is what you are expecting, then you can accomplish with below steps.

1. With 0 0 0 0 as the start of the record, join the consequent lines before you see another 0 0 0 0 pattern.

This can be accomplished using

```
$ perl -ne ' if( /(?=^\s*0\s+0\s+0\s+0\s+?)(^.+?)\n/smgo ) { print "\n$1" } else { chomp($_); print "$_" } '  block_zeros.txt

         0           0           0           0      5522     -365290     -441287      -78074    -39490      -30774        7921       82126   1391898     1139913      792801     2672554
         0           0           0           0      4906     -366163     -441744      -77614    -39125      -31009        7332       81061   1412373     1142806      793817     2837307
         0           0           0           0     15965     -463075     -549574      -89243    -64152      -45009       17963      103367   -189486     -165820     -128253     -236536   1243199     1029337      734157     2290154
         0           0           0           0      5000     -300000     -400000      -70000    -30000      -30000        7000       80000
         0           0           0           0
$
```

2. Now remove the pattern that you don't need. Pipe the above output to another perl command as below

   $ perl -ne ' if( /(?=^\s*0\s+0\s+0\s+0\s+?)(^.+?)\n/smgo ) { print "\n$1" } else { chomp($*); print "$*" } '  block_zeros.txt | perl -ne ' if(! /(^\s*0\s+0\s+0\s+0\s+15965)/omg ) { print }  '

   ```
         0           0           0           0      5522     -365290     -441287      -78074    -39490      -30774        7921       82126   1391898     1139913      792801     2672554
         0           0           0           0      4906     -366163     -441744      -77614    -39125      -31009        7332       81061   1412373     1142806      793817     2837307
         0           0           0           0      5000     -300000     -400000      -70000    -30000      -30000        7000       80000
         0           0           0           0
   ```

   $
3. Again, explode using awk

   $ perl -ne ' if( /(?=^\s*0\s+0\s+0\s+0\s+?)(^.+?)\n/smgo ) { print "\n$1" } else { chomp($*); print "$*" } '  block_zeros.txt | perl -ne ' if(! /(^\s*0\s+0\s+0\s+0\s+15965)/omg ) { print }  ' | awk ' BEGIN{OFS="\t" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i=i+4) { print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2),$(i+3)  } }  ' | column -t
   0        0        0        0
   5522     -365290  -441287  -78074
   -39490   -30774   7921     82126
   1391898  1139913  792801   2672554
   0        0        0        0
   4906     -366163  -441744  -77614
   -39125   -31009   7332     81061
   1412373  1142806  793817   2837307
   0        0        0        0
   5000     -300000  -400000  -70000
   -30000   -30000   7000     80000
   0        0        0        0
   $